# Why isn't my new column being named correctly when using a Python Data Function in Spotfire

Tags: python, spotfire

I've used TERR to make calculated columns and other types of data functions in Spotfire and am happy to hear you can now use Python. I did a simple test to ensure things are working (x3 = x2*2) - that's literally script i wrote in the python data function window and then set up the input paramters (x2 as a column) and the output paramters (x3) to be a new column....the values come out fine but the newly calculated column comes out as named x2(2)....i looked into the input/output parameters and all the names are correct, yet the column still comes out named that way. My concern is that this is uber simple, yet why is the column not being named what is in the script even though everything is set up correct. There is even a Youtube video by a Spotfire employee, the same thing happens to them and the don't mention it at all.

Has anybody else run across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to differ from how the equivalent TERR data function works. I consulted with the Spotfire engineering team, and here is what they suggest. It has to do with how a Column input is handled internally in Python vs TERR. In both Python and TERR, inputs (and outputs) are passed over as a table. In TERR's case a data.frame, and in Python's case a pandas.DataFrame.  In TERR's case though, if the Data Function says the input is a Column, this is actually converted from a 1-column data.frame to a vector of the equivalent type; similarly, for a Value it is converted from its 1x1 data.frame to a scalar type.  In Python,  Value inputs are treated the same, but  Column inputs are left as a pandas.Series, which retains the column name from the original input column.
Maybe you can try something different.  You wouldn't want to convert it to a standard Python list, because in that case, x2*2 would actually make the column twice as long, rather than a vectorised arithmetic operation.  But you could make it a straight numpy array instead.  You can try adding "x2 = x2.to_numpy()" at the top of your example, and see if the result matches what you expected.